# Formulários C# Windows Forms Não Abrem Após Atualização VS 2013 para VS 2015

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015

Instalei o Visual Studio 2015 e abri um projeto do VS 2013, depois disso os forms do C# Windows Forms antigos não abrem.

Uso o F5, aparece o menu de debug mas não abre nada na tela, aparece o projeto rodando no gerenciador de tarefas mas nada aparece na tela.

Criei um form novo e coloquei para iniciar por ele e funciona, ou seja, os formulários novos que crio abrem normal, os antigos não abrem mais.

No VS 2013 também não roda mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executável estava relacionado com o Visual Studio 2013, desinstalei o VS 2013, limpei todos registros, voltei no VS2015 e funcionou.